# Grok pattern to parse this in logstash and index to Elasticsearch

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have a sample log file which needs to be parsed and index into Elasticsearch. I am looking for grok pattern to parse the same. How should I look at multiline events and parsing this file.

https://pastebin.com/TgX2t8Xj

```
1533049141.394300 IP 193.169.252.32.37906 > 66.135.211.96.80: Flags 
[P.], seq 1685009963:1685011342, ack 1304322535, win 29200, length 
1379: HTTP: POST /services/search/FindingService/v1 HTTP/1.1
E.....@.@...... B..`...Pdo6+M.a.P.r../..POST 
/services/search/FindingService/v1 HTTP/1.1
Host: 66.135.211.96
Content-Length: 710
Accept: 
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
X-Ebay-SOA-Request-Data-Format: XML
X-EBAY-SOA-GLOBAL-ID: EBAY-DE
X-EBAY-SOA-SECURITY-APPNAME: eBayInc80-8977-4f05-a933-3daa1311213
X-EBAY-SOA-SERVICE-NAME: FindingService
X-EBAY3PP-DEVICE-ID: 31ac18b8-35f3-5a1e-9670-c30ccbf8596e,1,01
X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME: findItemsAdvanced
X-EBAY-SOA-SERVICE-VERSION: 1.11.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
User-Agent: eBayiPhone/2.5.2
```

I assume this is one event, need a grok pattern for this.
Would love to hear any responses on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to combine the lines with logstash's [multiline codec plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-multiline.html).  With it, you specify a pattern that would delineate one message from the next, and it combines them into one string.

After that, you would build up a grok pattern to match and extract the data you needed.  Using the [grok debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) is a great way of doing that.  Start from the left, and go slowly.